# php-fpm container does not want to start

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, laradock

I try to start laradock container for my new project, however, I am getting a weird error which I cannot find the documentation on. Can you help me out?

```
$ sudo docker-compose up -d nginx mysql phpmyadmin redis workspace
```

results in

> ERROR: for docker-in-docker  Cannot start service docker-in-docker: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:459: container init caused: process_linux.go:422: setting cgroup config for procHooks process caused: resulting devices cgroup doesn't match target mode: unknown
> ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

redis, mysql and phpmyadmin work well

```
           Name                          Command                State                   Ports
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
laradock_docker-in-docker_1   dockerd-entrypoint.sh            Exit 128
laradock_mysql_1              docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up         0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
laradock_phpmyadmin_1         /docker-entrypoint.sh apac ...   Up         0.0.0.0:8081->80/tcp
laradock_redis_1              docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up         0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp
```

Comment: Run `docker container logs laradock_docker-in-docker_1` if it's your `php-fpm` container to see the logs and errors

Comment: i'm facing similar issues currently, and it seems that there are known issues between docker v20 and some virtualization providers (like Virtuozzo). If you are running your docker on a hosted virtual server, then this could be an issue for you as well.  Sadly, my Provider reject every request to look into the issue, as they pretend to have tested everything very well... but a few weeks ago everything worked and i changed nothing... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯